# How do i get a picture box to go over another one in Visual Basic

Tags: picturebox

in [image] picture i would like the prices to go over the other picture box which is the words "premium Roast Coffee" however it is just cutting the image on top. I have it on the top most of layer of images.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click the PictureBox then choose bring to front or add this to your Load event

picturebox1.BringToFront()